# split and update string in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a set of strings in my textbox seperated with a comma each. i want to split them and update their record in db for each of the strings in the split. after running my code it only updates the first string and leave the rest. Here is my code.

```
Dim serialnumberlist = Split(txtserial.Text, ",").ToList
For Each serial As String In serialnumberlist 
    'update their branches
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstring").ConnectionString

    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "Update scratchcards set branches=@branches where Pin_Serial=@serial"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branches", ddlbranches.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", serial)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
Next
Response.Write("<script>alert('Branches allocated successfully!');</script>")
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it i.e. step through the code and observe the variables?

Comment: What does txtserial.Text look like..show an example, is it truly comma separated or is it comma space.

Comment: And you REALLY don't want to keep opening and closing con every loop....

Comment: The [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function expects the separator first as the *first* argument. You should probably use the `String.Split` method to avoid such confustion, eg `txtserial.Text.Split(',')`. You don't need the call to `ToList` either, `For Each` works on any IEnumerable type

Comment: txtserial.test looks like this PA/3/0000001740,
PA/1/0000004583,
PA/4/0000000095,

Comment: BTW: If that is not a very long list, you can change that query to do them all at once using Pin_Serial In("","","","")

Comment: @Trevor not without resorting to strinc concatenations. You can use table-valued parameters and get rid of the entire loop.

Comment: @Dipa That's a comma **and** a space. You need to split either by `", "` or try the overload that accepts multiple separators, in this case `{",", " "}`

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, apart from a certain inefficiency. Perhaps the input is empty, or contains consecutive separators? You could avoid this confusion by using [String.Split(Char(), StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, which will remove empty entries.

If you suspect that theere may be multiple separators in the string, eg space-comma, you can add more separators in the `separators` array.

As others have commented, you shouldn't rebuild the connection and command in each iteration. Your code should change to this:

```
Dim separators() As String = {","}
Dim serialnumberlist = txtserial.Text.Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
'update their branches
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstring").ConnectionString

Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Update scratchcards set branches=@branches where Pin_Serial=@serial"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@branches", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@serial", SqlDbType.NVarChar,30)                

        'At the moment of execution
        cmd.Parameters("@branches").Value=ddlbranches.SelectedValue
        con.Open()
        For Each serial As String In serialnumberlist 
            cmd.Parameters("@serial").Value=serial
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Using

Response.Write("<script>alert('Branches allocated successfully!');</script>")
```

Only the parameter value needs to change for each iteration. 
You don't need to call `.ToList()` after split as `For Each` works with any IEnumerable

You can create the command in advance, even store it in a field for reuse. You only need to set a new `Connection` befor each execution.

**UPDATE**

From the comments, it seems that the input data contains both a comma *and* a space, ie `PA/3/0000001740, PA/1/0000004583, PA/4/0000000095`. To split this, the separator string `,` should be used, ie:

```
Dim separators() As String = {", "}
```

If there is *any* chance that a column may start withouth the space, the `separators` array should contain both characters, ie:

```
Dim separators() As String = {",", " "}
```

or

```
Dim separators() As String = {", ",","}
```

**Performance**

Finally, the best performance for this update can be achieved if only one query is performed, ie `UPDATE ... WHERE Pin_Serial in (....)`. This is risky though, as `IN` expressions can't accept parameters. If the serials were numbers, one could validate the input and just join the keys. With text though, it's possible that unexpected values will create problems.

In this case, the query can be modified to use a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). That's a bit more involved though, and requires creating a table type in the database:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PinTableType AS TABLE ( Pin_Serial nvarchar(50) )
```

Once this is done though, the loop can become a single query:

```
UPDATE scratchcards
set branches=@branches
from scratchcards inner join @serialsTable on myTable.Pin_Serial=scratchcards.Pin_Serial
```

The `@serialsTable` parameter will have to be of type `DataTable`. I'll cheat a bit and use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) and [ToDataTable()](https://morelinq.github.io/2.1/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ToDataTable.htm) :

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE scratchcards
set branches=@branches
from scratchcards inner join @serialsTable on myTable.Pin_Serial=scratchcards.Pin_Serial"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@branches", SqlDbType.Int)    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@serialsTable",SqlDbType.Structured)

'At the moment of execution
cmd.Parameters("@branches").Value =ddlbranches.SelectedValue
Dim table as DataTable = serialnumberlist.ToDataTable()
cmd.Parameters("@serialsTable").Value=table
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: Sorry, you are missinformed..click on your own link.

Comment: @Trevor oops, you are right. I **never** used the Split function since I left VB6 in 2003. Still, I suspect that barring invalid input, the cleaned up code will perform better

Comment: Yup, original was very inefficient. I still suspect its comma space separated text though... typical error.

Comment: not working...still updating just 1 record among 5 serial numbers in the textbox

Comment: its working now. there was nothing wrong with the code. it was the space inbetween the commas that stopped the execution. Thank you very much

Comment: @Trevor yes, you can use a Table-Valued parameter and get rid of the loop. That wasn't the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I thought, it's comma space... Either split on ", " or better, use the trim function

```
Dim serialnumberlist = Split(txtserial.Text, ",").ToList
For Each serial As String In serialnumberlist 
'update their branches
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstring").ConnectionString

Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
      cmd.Connection = con  
      cmd.CommandText = "Update scratchcards set branches=@branches where Pin_Serial=@serial"
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branches", ddlbranches.SelectedValue)
      cmd.Paramaters.Add("@Serial", SqlDbType.Text)
      For Each serial As String In serialnumberlist
            cmd.Parameters("@Serial").Value = Trim(serial) '<--------HERE
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Next       
   End Using
End Using

Response.Write("<script>alert('Branches allocated successfully!');</script>")
```

Comment: Consider using `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`. `AddWithValue` has been depreciated.

Comment: @Bugs [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) has *not* been deprecated, but `Add(string, dbType)` is better.

Comment: @Plutonix is that just MySQL then?

Comment: I think aswell, you would have to clear your parameters on each loop if using `AddWithValue`. I haven't tested so not to sure but my feeling is it will try adding `@serial` multiple times. If using `Add` you could declare outside the loop and then set the value inside he loop.

Comment: @Bugs it's bad MySQL docs, possibly bad implementation quality too. `AddWithValue` has issues because it *guesses* types and sizes. This can lead to a lot of problems, eg if a `double` is guessed when the column is a `numeric(9,4)` or if the wrong size is used for a string field

Comment: @Bugs other examples of a (very) bad MySQL implementation - the async methods aren't async, They fake asynchrony by using a background thread. *Asynchronous* means that no threads are used, instead Windows' native asynchronous IO model takes care of notifying the application once an IO op completes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the information. I didn't know about the async methods, that's a new one for me.

Comment: @Bugs MySQL's connector has quite a few quirks that get covered up instead of fixed. ADO.NET (and ADO before it) had asynchronous operations for over a decade. MySQL initially rejected the feature request. In the end, they were implemented as a .... delegate invocation. This lead to an alternative community OSS implementation, [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this way:

```
Dim serialnumberlist As String() = txtserial.Text.Split(","C)
For Each item As String In serialnumberlist 
    Using con As New SqlConnection("")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Update scratchcards set branches=@branches where Pin_Serial=@serial", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branches", ddlbranches.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", item )


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: What did you change? How does this answer the question? A code-only answer doesn't help anyone.